# jQuery Dialog, load href as an image source into a dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, dialog, load

I am trying to open an image into a jQuery dialog. When I click on href link, I want to load this href into a dialog.

Markup:

```
        <a href="www.blahblahblah.com/blah.jpg" class="slideshow_zoom">Link</a>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.slideshow_zoom').each(function() {
    var $link = $(this);

    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
         .load($link.attr('href'))
         .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               resizable: false,
               modal: true,
               width: 1000,
               closeOnEscape: true,
               dialogClass:'zoom'
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
    });
});
```

This markup and jquery code only produce a dialog with nothing in it. Im guessing it is not actually loading the href...or maybe it is that the href needs to be changed into an image src in order for it to be viewed. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to use the callback function of `.load()`.

Comment: Your href isn't a valid URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the `.dialog()` method on an `img`:

```
var $dialog = $('<img src="' + $link.attr('href') + '" />')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizeable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 1000,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        dialogClass: 'zoom'
    });
```